# Django ModelForm in admin saving multiple times

Tags: django, mezzanine

I'm trying to implement a simple function that sends an email if a checkbox is checked in the admin when you save. eg: A simple article is entered into the admin, when i hit save it sends the content of the article (if the checkbox is checked). got that working but for some reason it's sending 3 times! 
there's far too much code to post here but this should be enough to see what's going on, If it helps some of this if from the mezzanine blog admin section (which i've cloned).

```
class YourModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    send_email = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
    def save(self, commit=True):
        send_email = self.cleaned_data.get('send_email', None)
        content = self.cleaned_data.get('content', None)
        if send_email == True:
            print 'sending' #email stuff here 
        return super(YourModelForm, self).save(commit=commit)

    class Meta:
        model = Ite
        fields = '__all__'

class IteAdmin(TweetableAdminMixin, DisplayableAdmin, OwnableAdmin):
    form = YourModelForm
    readonly_fields=('email_sent',)
    fieldsets = ite_fieldsets 


    def save_form(self, request, forms, change):
        """
        Super class ordering is important here - user must get saved first.
        """
        OwnableAdmin.save_form(self, request, forms, change)
        return DisplayableAdmin.save_form(self, request, forms, change)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that admin ModelForm is a good place for triggering mail send.
I suggest using signals like this:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

class MyModel(models.Model):
    ...


def send_mail_for_my_model(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        print "send mail"
        #email stuff

post_save.connect(send_mail_for_my_model, sender=MyModel)
```

I guess in your case:
OwnableAdmin.save_form() calls YourModelForm.save, thus sending mail.
Than DisplayableAdmin.save_form() calls YourModelForm.save, sending mail again.
This happens because first argument of save_form(self) is instance of IteAdmin with form attribute set to YourModelForm and each class subclasses ModelAdmin.

I guess you should use approach like that if you want to use ModelForm:

```
class OwnableAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    def save_form(self, request, forms, change):
        #do your actions
        return super(OwnableAdmin, self).save_form(request, forms, change)


class DisplayableAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    def save_form(self, request, forms, change):
        #do your actions
        return super(DisplayableAdmin, self).save_form(request, forms, change)


class TweetableAdminMixin(object):
    ...    


class IteAdmin(OwnableAdmin, DisplayableAdmin, TweetableAdminMixin):
    form = YourModelForm
    readonly_fields=('email_sent',)
    fieldsets = ite_fieldsets 

    def save_form(self, request, forms, change):
        #do your actions
        return super(IteAdmin, self).save_form(request, forms, change)
```

By the way, in python3 you can use super() without arguments.

Maybe in your case it'll be fine to each model to inherit from the other like:

```
class TweetableAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    ...

class DisplayableAdmin(TweetableAdmin):
    ...


class OwnableAdmin(DisplayableAdmin):
    ...

class IteAdmin(OwnableAdmin):
    ...
```

Anyway, I recommend reading this articles about python super:

http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=236275

Comment: Signals look cool! thanks but i'm still left with the same problem. I need the modelForm (i think) because the checkbox is separate from the model. As in i only want to send a mail if it's checked so i needed to create the form to get it's value (which isn't saved with the model). any suggestions for a better approach much appreciated

Comment: OwnableAdmin.save_form() invokes YourModelForm.save(), thus sending mail.
Than DisplayableAdmin.save_form() invokes YourModelForm.save, sending mail again.
This happens because first argument of save_form(self) is instance of IteAdmin with form attribute set to YourModelForm.
You should change the approach.

Comment: I guess you should call super(IteAdmin, self) in IteAdmin.save_form just once. It will call TweetableAdminMixin.save_form method which will do his job(saving model) and in the end will call super(TweetableAdminMixin, self).save form and so on.
And you should reorder class inheritance like this:
class IteAdmin(OwnableAdmin, DisplayableAdmin, TweetableAdminMixin):

Comment: Thanks man, I'm completely lost but cheers for pointing out where the problem lies. I'm struggling to get my head round 'super' , going to read up on it. please edit your answer with the info about Ownable and Displayable calling twice so i can mark it correct. cheers

Comment: Updated answer. I hope it'll help you.